# Mi escritorio se convirtió en un repositorio local

Tags: visual-studio, vscode, github

parece que cuando estaba aprendiendo y probando cosas sobre gitHub sin querer hice que mi Escritorio/Desktop sea un repositorio local.
En mi visual code ahora se muestra cada cambio que hago en mi Escritorio.
Como hago para que mi Escritorio no sea un repositorio local? Obviamente sin eliminar ningun archivo.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema pero en visual studio como lo soluciono?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que en tu vscode se ha puesto verde en la seccion de repositorio, a mi me paso con Git-bash, en el momento no sabia y elimine la carpeta, debes eliminar el repo, no los archivos.Al tenerlo activado en tu escritorio debe haber una carpeta oculta que se llama .git al eliminarla eliminas el repositorio, mas bien las copias que guarda tu repositorio mas no los archivos.
Para "cancelar" el git init debes pararte en la carpeta escritorio e insertar el comando:

```
rm -rf .git
```

Esto vaciara la rama de git que tenias

Espero que te sirva:)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Me paso lo mismo y para solucionarlo me funciono el comando:

> rm -rf .git

Para ejecutarlo correctamente debes primero posicionarte en la ruta donde se encuentra tu .\ESCRITORIO o .\DESKTOP

Importante saber que el comando debes ejecutarlo en la terminal de git bash